# Docker java .jar won't run

Tags: java, docker

I'm trying to run my Java game in Docker, but when i try to run it i get this error message
`Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/src/app/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar`

**Dockerfile**

```
# Base image
FROM java:8

#COPY . /usr/src/app
#WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Get Code v0.0.6 from Github
ADD  ["https://github.com/JohnnyDeeee/Oils-Well/blob/master/Builds/v0.0.6/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar", "/usr/src/app/"]

# DEBUG
RUN chmod +x "/usr/src/app/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar"
RUN ls -al /usr/src/app

# Start the Game
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/src/app/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar"]
```

and this is how i build
`docker build -t oilswell-v0.0.6 .`

and run my image 
`docker run oilswell-v0.0.6`

Comment: Are you able to open the jar as a zip archive by changing its filename extension?

Comment: @dorukayhan yes, on my windows OS

Comment: Are you able to run the jar outside the docker environment? jar files also get corrupted if the signature mismatches from the classes i believe.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work once fixed. Running GUI applications within a docker container is possible but kind of hackish https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/ (and to my knowledge impossible on a windows host unless you have a full blown graphical VM linux running)

Comment: @zapl The answer fixed my issue, but i think you are right.. I got some errors from my game and didnt see any GUI, so i'll take a look at you link thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way Github serves files, currently you are pulling this exact page from Github...

https://github.com/JohnnyDeeee/Oils-Well/blob/master/Builds/v0.0.6/v0.0.6%20-%20FINAL.jar

Which if you open it, you'll see it's not your JAR, but the page showing the JAR within the GIT repository. The URL you actually need is...

https://github.com/JohnnyDeeee/Oils-Well/blob/master/Builds/v0.0.6/v0.0.6%20-%20FINAL.jar?raw=true

This will return the actual JAR, rather than the HTML page. So your Dockerfile should look like this...

```
# Base image
FROM java:8

ADD ["https://github.com/JohnnyDeeee/Oils-Well/blob/master/Builds/v0.0.6/v0.0.6%20-%20FINAL.jar?raw=true", "/usr/src/app/"]
RUN chmod +x "/usr/src/app/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar"

# Start the Game
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/src/app/v0.0.6 - FINAL.jar"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. Now i got some errors coming from my game, probably because GUI apps dont run withing docker..?